# CGAL 2.5D Triangulation Attach vertex info

Tags: c++, cgal

so I currently have a 2.5D Delaunay Triangulation working using this setup.

```
    typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
    typedef CGAL::Triangulation_euclidean_traits_xy_3<K> Gt;
    typedef CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<Gt> Delaunay;
    typedef K::Point_3 Point_3;
```

But I want to attach additional information to each vertex. I am using this setup because the 3D data is LiDAR and thus constrained. This method has worked well but I just need to attach addition information to each vertex.

This is what i've attempted to use, but the template for Delaunay_triangulation_2 doesn't allow for this many arguments. Any ideas?

```
    typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
    typedef CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2<unsigned int, K> Vb;
    typedef CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<Vb> Tds;
    typedef CGAL::Exact_triangulation_euclidean_traits_xy_3<K> Gt;
    typedef CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<K,Gt,Tds> Delaunay;
```

Comment: K and Gt are redundant, why did you add K in there? Did you check the doc?

Comment: From what I understood the K was necessary. Even if I remove the K and use <Gt,Tds> I get lots of internal errors with CGAL detailing that the point needs to be 2 dimensional and not 3. The Gt is necessary because I am using 3D points in a constrained 2D triangulation.

Comment: Well, please provide an actual testcase... Delaunay_triangulation_2 only takes 2 parameters, so the K will have to go anyway. Projection_traits_xy_3 replaces the euclidean_traits_xy thing.

Comment: And maybe vertex_base would be happier getting Gt instead of K.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've put you a complete example [on github](https://gist.github.com/afabri/1c12a9c0c32fd6cbe22fee72e4a10984) and filed a [pull request](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/pull/1848)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much. I appreciate the help!